# SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Please help me, i get this errors when i run my app use Idea

here is screen of error

http://prntscr.com/en3lcu

here is part of code where create table

```
    private String getTableDDL(final Class<? extends GlassContract.Table> table) {
    return getTableDDL(table, GlassContract.getTableName(table));
}

private String getTableDDL(final Class<? extends GlassContract.Table> table, String tableName) {
    final StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(128);
    sql.append("create table ").append(tableName).append(" (");
    for (final Field field : table.getFields()) {
        if (field.getName().startsWith("_") || field.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class))
            continue;
        try {
            sql.append(field.get(null));
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
        try {
            final Field type = table.getDeclaredField("_SQL_" + field.getName() + "_TYPE");
            sql.append(' ').append(type.get(null));
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            sql.append(" TEXT");
        }
        sql.append(',');
    }

    try {
        final Field type = table.getDeclaredField("_PK_COMPOSITE");
        sql.append("PRIMARY KEY(").append(type.get(null)).append(")");
        sql.append(',');
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        // ignore
    }
    try {
        final Field type = table.getDeclaredField("_UNIQUE_COMPOSITE");
        sql.append("UNIQUE(").append(type.get(null)).append(")");
        sql.append(',');
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        // ignore
    }

    sql.setLength(sql.length() - 1); // chop off last comma

    sql.append(')');
    Log.v(TAG, "DDL for " + table.getSimpleName() + ": " + sql);
    return sql.toString();
}
```

I please help me, because I break my head))

Comment: Please post the error message in the body of the question.

Comment: What does `getTableDDL()` actually return?

Comment: You simply can't use the reserved keyword `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really trying to create text fields in your table that are named `null`?

Even if this works (and I am not sure it does), you are duplicating this and creating two identically named fields called `null`

Answer (score 0):

The first field in that `CREATE TABLE` statement doesn't have a proper name (it is "null").  That's why it blows up.

There's more fields with illegal names as well.